# PHP's html_entity_decode() in Python

Tags: php, python, decode, html-entities, utf8-decode

Let's say I have a file **a.txt** which contains html encoded HTML, sth like this:

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>HTML preview</title>
            <link rel="StyleSheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body>&lt;!doctype html&gt;&lt;html itemscope=&quot;&quot;
        ...
        &lt;/script&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</body>
        </html>
```

In PHP I can do:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('a.txt');
$start = strpos ($content, '<body>') + 6;
$end = strpos ($content, '</body>');
$html = html_entity_decode(substr($content, $start, $end-$start));
file_put_contents('b.html');
```

And it works perfectly. The file **b.html** becomes a proper HTML.

My question is: How can I do that in Python, assuming the file and encoded content is in UTF-8?

Edit: I experimented a bit with HTMLParser and BeautifulStoneSoup, but they corrupt UTF-8 encoding. I experimented with UnicodeDammit, but returning string to console or file brings an exception that chars are out of range.

Edit 2: Please answer with a code examples which work in the similar manner.

**Solution 1**

[Python's version of html_entity_decode()](https://gist.github.com/elus/607454)

Comment: Have you had a look at "Unescaping" section in https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml ?

Comment: I would like to use something that does not require to manually predict all possible html entities to be transformed.

Comment: Scroll down further. Also take a look at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/elus/607454).

Comment: is this your preferred output: `'<!doctype html><html itemscope=""...</script></body></html>'` I just got it using `HTMLParser`